# GET request for media files in WP REST API 2 results in an empty array

Tags: rest-api

**EDIT: I have reported the issue to the development team of the plugin and they have resolved it in BETA10 version of the plugin.**

---

I have been trying to fetch all the **media files** from the REST API using restangular, but no matter how I try it fails, so I decided to test the media endpoint via PostMan app and realized that although I can see the media files json object in my browsers when I browse to `/wp-json/wp/v2/media` but using **PostMan** or using **restangular** it always results in an **empty array**.

The funny part is that during the time I was pulling my hair for getting the media files, the files showed up only once, and after one refresh they were gone forever, this could be a bug in the wp rest plugin v2beta9.

Comment: It works correctly here, both from Postman and restangular. You may need to peform some debug and provide deeply information.

Comment: @cybmeta I have ran all sorts of testings on it, I am not getting errors in my console or anywhere else. In fact if I use the same code, but change the route from media to /wp-json/wp/v2/users or /wp-json/wp/v2/posts I will get the objects for the users or the posts, but for /wp-json/wp/v2/media it will just gives me an empty array. Any ideas?

Comment: It may be the basic authentication falling (I see you are using it on the screenshot), so please provide add all the information to the question, and this about Basic Authentication is important information you missed. We can not paly to "guess". Again, it works perfectly here; no issue at all.

Comment: @cybmeta As I explained before, I have ran all sorts of tests on it, with or without authentication, restnagular uses wp_nonce authentication, fails to get the object with no errors, I also tried postman with basic authentication, and without any authentications at all. Both fails without any errors. I will try it on another system too (windows PC) to make sure it's not a local bug.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't guess it from "I did all sort of tests" (just joking, do you see how that is a guessing play?). Sorry again but if you don't provide a full example we can use to reproduce the issue we can not help. I hope you understand.

Comment: @cybmeta I did more tests and I realized that I can only access the media endpoint object when I am logged out, the only logged in user role that would still show the media object is the subscriber user role, I tested it with admin, editor, author and contributor roles and it wouldn't work.

The result is the same in my app (using angularJS) and in the PostMan for mac, so this can not be an issue with my testing environment. Could you please test again with PostMan + authentication using **JSON Basic Authentication** plugin to see if you could recreate the situation on your side?

Comment: [With this plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth)? Let me try.

Comment: @cybmeta Yes, that's the one.

Comment: Same results here. Media endpoint list media files only for guest users and subscribers. I've reproduced the issue using cURL and Basic Authentication plugin. Have you report this issue already? I've found [almost the same thread in Github](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1959).

Comment: Yes it's reported and they have labeled it as a bug, hopefully will be fixed in beta 10.